# Filter child entity in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Is there anyway to write a query in jpa that filters child entities?

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity =  Flow.class)
    private Flow flow;
}
```

Flow entity:

```
@Entity
public class Flow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Step.class)
    private List<Step> steps;
}
```

Now I would like to get the project and his flow but the steps in the flow should be filtered on a start and endtime property.

What I'm doing right now is find the project and then loop trough all the steps and filter the steps.

Like this:

```
List<Step> steps = project.getFlow().getSteps();
List<Step> filteredSteps = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < steps.size(); i++) {
    Step step = steps.get(i);

    if (step.getStartTime() == null || step.getEndTime() == null) {
        break;
    }

    if (step.getStartTime().isAfter(start) && step.getEndTime().isBefore(end)) {
        filteredSteps.add(step);
    }
}
```

Step entity:

```
@Entity
public class Step {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
}
```

I don't see how I can add a query in my project repository which is a crudrepository to filter the steps in a child entity.

Comment: you can annotate the repository with `@Query()`

Comment: show your step class

Comment: added the step entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function like this in your Repository should be enough.

```
findByFlow_Steps_StartTimeAfterAndFlow_Steps_EndTimeBefore(Date startTime, Date endTime);
```

Comment: I've tried it like this ```Project findByFlow_Steps_StartTimeAfterAndEndTimeBefore(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime);``` but then I get the error that No property endTime found for type Project. So it seems to me he is looking for endTime in project and not in the steps. Also here it seems to me I get all the projects. I have the id for my project I just want to filter out some steps

Comment: there was a small mistake. edited my code. just check. If you look at the error, it was complaining for endTime and not startTime. So it was evident there was something wrong with only endTime :)

Comment: Yes thank you :-). Question If you for example want to add the project Id in this query is this even possible?

Comment: Yes of course try this findByIdAndFlow_Steps_StartTimeAfterAndFlow_Steps_EndTimeBefore and pass id also as argument

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: pvpkiran just for asking this returns all the steps so If I want to remove the steps that doesn't fit the timestamp I need to do this manually?